# Multiple alignment in a row Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following layout [image]

This has the text aligned to the center and the image is aligned to the end of the parent. I'm in the process of learning Jetpack compose and was wondering if it is possible for the children of the row to specify their alignment (gravity)?

I can achieve the above layout using a constraint layout.

Here is my current solution:

```
 ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        val (logo, avatar) = createRefs()
        Text(
            text = "Some Text",
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(logo) {
                centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
                centerVerticallyTo(parent)
            }
        )
        Image(
            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Person,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.profile_pic),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(4.dp)
                .constrainAs(avatar) {
                    start.linkTo(logo.end)
                    linkTo(logo.end, parent.end, bias = 1f)
                }
        )

    }
```

Can this also be achieved using a `Row/Column` setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look so simple.

Column+Row:

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Row(
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ){
                    Box(Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Text(
                        "Simple text",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    )
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                            contentDescription = "Icon",
                        Modifier.weight(1f)
                    )
                }
            }
```

Box:

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(
                        "Simple text",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                        contentDescription = "Icon",
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                    )
                }
```